# Pig strings coming into Python UDF

Tags: python, apache-pig, jython

I've found some posts on how to *return* various datatypes from Python to Pig, but I haven't seen any useful documentation on what a Python UDFs *receive* when Pig sends it data, and I'm hoping someone can clear this up for me. Specifically, my strings aren't coming in as Python `str` values on Azure (Pig 0.12).

I have a simple dataset that I group:

```
records = LOAD 'path/to/file.tsv';
grp = GROUP records BY $0;
DUMP grp;
(John,{(John,Smith,123 Main St,john@smith.com)})
(Jane,{(Jane,Doe,456 7th St,jane@doe.com)},(Jane,Doe,789 First Ave,jane@doe.com)})
<and so on>
```

When I create my UDF, I try returning something that will give me a hint as to what it gets:

```
def foo(input):
    if type(input) == str: return input
    if type(input) == int: return str(input)

    try:
        rep = ', '.join([ foo(field) for field in input])
        return "[" + str(type(input)) + ": " + rep + "]"
    except:
        # input isn't iterable
        return str(type(input))
```

So I pass my data in:

```
REGISTER 'path/to/myUdfs.py' USING jython AS myUdfs;
fooResults = FOREACH grp GENERATE myUdfs.foo($1);
```

And the results indicate there are no `str` values but rather arrays of ints:

```
([<type 'list'>: [<type 'tuple'>: [<type 'array.array'>: 74, 111, 104, 110],  <type 'NoneType'>, [<type 'array.array'>: 83, 109,...
```

It's obvious that these values are the text I'm getting, but they show up as an `array` of `int`s instead of the desired `str`. I haven't seen any indication that this is normal behavior. Is this a behavior of Pig on Azure? Something that can be easily changed?

Comment: Maybe if you specify a loading schema you will get different results. E.g. `records = LOAD 'path/to/file.tsv' as (name:chararrray, surname:chararray, ...)` By default everything is a bytearray which is what you are seeing in the UDF.

Comment: I'm not specifying a loading schema because I don't know ahead of time how many columns my input file will have. (I do know I need to group by the first column.) Is there a way to load an arbitrary number of chararray fields (ie, default to chararray instead of bytearray)?

Comment: You could try using CSVExcelStorage in piggybank, or write your own load function.